# A word that exist in Russia that mean "rehiability politically", how do you write it?

Tags: word

A word that I came across from [this](https://youtu.be/50pQHccrlHg?t=502) video. Just wounder how it is pronounced (because she say a long sentence) and primarely how it is spelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This word is written as "[реабилитация](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)" 
Morphologically looks like

> ре-а-би-ли-та́-ци-я

This word has two meanings:
 1. restoration of human rights
 2. Human recovery after surgery / injury

Comment: I'd say "civil rights", not "human rights".